# Change Trait For Custom Block (GrapesJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grapesjs

I have built custom block in grapesJs in react. It is showing its default components settings but I want to replace it with my own when someone drags and drop my custom tool. I tried reading blogs but unable to solve problem

Default Component Settings That I Want To Replace With The Action Field For Form:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16ZaJkCDvsFaB5FCiwKyZ_wxXT1B_btN0/view?usp=sharing

Custom Block Code

```
import Icon from "../../assets/images/icons8-form-100.png";
export default function Form(editor) {
  return editor.BlockManager.add("#editor", {
    label: `<div>
    <img src=${Icon} width="50" style="filter:invert(1)" />
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    </div>`,
    type: "buttonLogin",
    content: `<style>body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      input[type="text"],
      select,
      textarea {
        padding: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-top: 6px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        resize: vertical;
        width: 90%;
      }
      
      input[type="submit"] {
        background-color: #0091ff;
        color: white;
        padding: 12px 30px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      
      input[type="submit"]:hover {
        background-color: #0091ff;
      }
      
      .container {
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }
      #form {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
      </style><div class="container">
    <h3>Contact Us</h3>
    <form id="form" action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
  
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" style="height:200px"></textarea>
  
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
  </div>`,
  });
}
```

App.JS

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import grapesjs from "grapesjs";
import gjsPresetWebpage from "grapesjs-preset-webpage";
import gjsBlocksBasic from "grapesjs-blocks-basic";
import gjsCountDown from "grapesjs-component-countdown";
import Form from "./plugins/form";
import "./styles/main.css";

function App() {
  // initilization of editor
  const initEditor = () => {
    const editor = grapesjs.init({
      container: "#editor",
      plugins: [gjsPresetWebpage, gjsBlocksBasic, gjsCountDown, Form],
      pluginsOpts: {
        gjsPresetWebpage: {},
        gjsBlocksBasic: {},
      },
    });

    editor.TraitManager.addType("buttonLogin", {
      /**
       * Returns the input element
       * @return {HTMLElement}
       */
      events: {
        click: function () {
          // trigger when btn is clicked
        },
      },
      getInputEl() {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.id = "btnLogin";
        button.value = "Login";
        return button;
      },
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initEditor();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="editor"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```